# Limiting c# user interface to one input

Tags: c#

I have written an application to determines whether the character enter is Uppercase, Lowercase or numerical. However, I was wondering how I could make the application limit the amount of characters a user can input to just one?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a character: ");
            char c = (char)Console.Read();
            if (Char.IsLetter(c))
            {
                if (Char.IsLower(c))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The character is lowercase");
                    Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The character is uppercase");
                    Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not an alphabetic character");
                Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        } // Try 

        catch {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if you use this `char c = (char)Console.ReadKey();` will it be exactly what you want?

Comment: You could use `Console.ReadKey`instead

Comment: Yes, changing it to this: try
           " {
                Console.Write("Enter a character: ");
                char c = (char)Console.ReadKey().KeyChar; " Limits it to just one, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Console.Write("Enter a character: ");
                char c = (char)Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                if (Char.IsLetter(c))
```

This will limit the entry to just one character

Comment: Wicked! Works fine now, limits the input to just one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot limit the amount of user inputs with `Console.Read();` as it only terminates when the user press the *Enter* key.

You can perhaps use the `Console.ReadKey();`. It will only obtain the next character pressed by the user and terminates the input immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your application. If you are using Winforms or WPF application than you can set maxlength to input controls. In console application, it is fine to just use Console.ReadKey().KeyChar to read one character only.